# Does the Flutter Riverpod missing_provider_scope lint rule have any side effects?

Tags: flutter, dart, lint, riverpod

Why does the **missing_provider_scope** Riverpod lint rule exist? Are there any side effects when using it in a deeply nested widget?

In following official Riverpod example https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/examples/todos/lib/main.dart, it's not at the top of the widget tree.

I typically have a widget tree like this:
=> FutureBuilder (waiting for backend data) => ProviderScope => MaterialApp

Answer (score 1):

The emphasis here is specifically on the absence of `ProviderScope` in the widget tree. Technically, it can be embedded (and overridden) in any part of the widget tree. But it's worth keeping in mind that it will apply to just this part of the widget tree.

So if you use a provider somewhere in the widget tree, but have not added `ProviderScope` at the root of that tree/subtree, the lint will cuss :)